# How to solve the recurrence relation $a_{1}=2, a_{n}=\frac{a_{n-1}+2}{2 a_{n-1}+1}(n \geq 2)$ with generating functions?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations, generating-functions

There's already a way to solve it, called "fixed point method", that is, from the relation we define its characteristic equation as $x=\dfrac{x+2}{2x+1}$，then we have $x_1=1,x_2=-1$. So the following relation established:
$$
\frac{a_{n}-1}{a_{n}+1}=\frac{\frac{a_{n-1}+2}{2 a_{n-1}+1}-1}{\frac{a_{n-1}+2}{2 a_{n-1}+1}+1}=-\frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{a_{n-1}-1}{a_{n-1}+1}
$$
It is obvious that $\displaystyle \frac{a_{n}-1}{a_{n}+1}=\frac{1}{3} \cdot\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n-1}$, and then we have $a_{n}=\dfrac{3^{n}-(-1)^{n}}{3^{n}+(-1)^{n}}$.

My question is, how to solve this kind of recurrence relations with **generating functions**? Also, "fixed points" can be applied to solving recurrences like $a_{n+1}=\dfrac{a_{n}^{2}+b}{2 a_{n}+d}$, which seems impossible to solve using generating functions.

Comment: Interesting solution technique. Any source?

Comment: @vonbrand Another way of viewing the technique is to observe that the function you're iterating is the projective-linear transformation represented by $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ i.e. if $a_{n-1} = \frac{p_{n-1}}{q_{n-1}}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}p_n\\q_n\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\2&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}p_{n-1}\\q_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}$ then $a_n=\frac{p_n}{q_n}$.  So then finding $a_n$ reduces to finding powers of the matrix which you can do by diagonalization.

Comment: @vonbrand the technique is frequenctly used in Math Olympiads. you may find it on AOPS. (I haven't searched for it on aops tho)

Comment: @DanielSchepler this perspective is quite good, but how to explain reccurences formed like $a_{n+1}=\dfrac{a_{n}^{2}+b}{2 a_{n}+d}$? In fact, there's proof that "fixed point" method **works** on $a_{n+1}=\dfrac{k a_{n}^{2}+b a_{n} + c}{p a_{n}+q}$ iff $p=2k, b=0$, and I am wondering if matrix multiplication still works.

Comment: @FFjet I would like to point out that the quadratic case is an analog of Chebyshev's polynomial at work, so that $f(x)=\coth(2\coth^{-1}x)=\dfrac{x^2+1}{2x}$, and the recurrence $a_{n+1}=\dfrac{a_n^2+b}{2a_n+d}$ becomes $wa_{n+1}+z=f(wa_n+z)$, where $w=(b+d^2/4)^{-1/2}$ and $z=dw/2$.

Comment: If you really want to use generating functions, just let $b_n = \frac1{a_n+1}$ (or anything else you prefer whose generating function has a closed-form), then apply the method to $(b_n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_0:=0$, and let
$$f(x):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$$
be the generating function of the sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq0}$. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=1$ this $f$ is even a bona fide analytic function in the unit disc. We have
$$a_n\bigl(1+(-1/3)^n\bigr)=(1-(-1/3)^n\bigr)\qquad(n\geq0)$$
and therefore
$$a_n\bigl(x^n+(-x/3)^n\bigr)=\bigl(x^n-(-x/3)^n\bigr)\qquad(n\geq0)\ .$$
This implies
$$f(x)+f\left(-{x\over3}\right)={1\over1-x}-{1\over1+{x\over3}}={4x\over(1-x)(3+x)}\qquad\bigl(|x|<1\bigr)$$
and shows that your generating function fulfills a certain functional equation.

I don't know what to make with this.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{%
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{a_{1}} & \ds{=} & \ds{2}
\\
\ds{a_{n}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{{a_{n - 1} + 2 \over 2 a_{n - 1} + 1}\,,\quad n \geq 2}
\end{array}\right.}}$

---

$\ds{\large Another\ Method}$: Lets $\ds{a_{n} \equiv x_{n}/y_{n}}$ such that
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{a_{n}  = {x_{n} \over y_{n}} =
{x_{n - 1}\,/y_{n - 1} + 2 \over 2x_{n - 1}\,/y_{n - 1} + 1} = {x_{n - 1} + 2y_{n - 1} \over 2x_{n - 1} + y_{n - 1}}}
\end{align}
and sets $\ds{\quad x_{n} = x_{n - 1} + 2y_{n - 1}\,,\quad
y_{n} = 2x_{n - 1} + y_{n - 1}}$ which is equivqlent to
\begin{align}
\pars{\begin{array}{c}\ds{x_{n}} \\ \ds{y_{n}}\end{array}}
& =
\pars{\begin{array}{cc}
\ds{1} & \ds{2}
\\
\ds{2} & \ds{1}
\end{array}}
\pars{\begin{array}{c}
\ds{x_{n - 1}} \\ \ds{y_{n - 1}}
\end{array}} =
\pars{\begin{array}{cc}
\ds{1} & \ds{2}
\\
\ds{2} & \ds{1}
\end{array}}^{2}
\pars{\begin{array}{c}
\ds{x_{n - 2}} \\ \ds{y_{n - 2}}
\end{array}}
\\[5mm] & = \cdots =
\pars{\begin{array}{cc}
\ds{1} & \ds{2}
\\
\ds{2} & \ds{1}
\end{array}}^{n - 1}
\pars{\begin{array}{c}
\ds{x_{1}} \\ \ds{y_{1}}
\end{array}} 
\end{align}
The above matrix has eigenvalues $\ds{\lambda_{1} = 3}$ and $\ds{\lambda_{2} = -1}$ with,
respectively, orthonormal eigenvectors
$\ds{{\bf u}_{1} = {1 \over \root{2}}{1 \choose 1}}$ and
$\ds{{\bf u}_{2} = {1 \over \root{2}}
{-1 \choose \phantom{-}1}}$. Then,
\begin{align}
\pars{\begin{array}{cc}
\ds{1} & \ds{2}
\\
\ds{2} & \ds{1}
\end{array}} & =
\sum_{j = 1}^{2}\lambda_{j}\,{\bf u}_{j}\,{\bf u}_{j}^{T}
\\[5mm] \mbox{and}\
\pars{\begin{array}{cc}
\ds{1} & \ds{2}
\\
\ds{2} & \ds{1}
\end{array}}^{n - 1} & =
\sum_{j = 1}^{2}\lambda_{j}^{n - 1}\,\,
{\bf u}_{j}\,{\bf u}_{j}^{T}
\\[2mm] & =
{ 1 \over 2}\pars{\begin{array}{cc}
\ds{3^{n -1} - \pars{-1}^{n}} & \ds{3^{n -1} + \pars{-1}^{n}}
\\
\ds{3^{n -1} + \pars{-1}^{n}} & \ds{3^{n -1} - \pars{-1}^{n}}
\end{array}}
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
a_{n} & =
{\bracks{3^{n - 1} - \pars{-1}^{n}}\ \overbrace{x_{1}/y_{1}}^{\ds{= a_{1} = 2}}\ +\ 3^{n - 1} + \pars{-1}^{n} \over
\bracks{3^{n - 1} + \pars{-1}^{n}}x_{1}/y_{1} + 3^{n - 1} - \pars{-1}^{n}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{3^{n} - \pars{-1}^{n} \over 3^{n} + \pars{-1}^{n}} \\ &
\end{align}